# SQL Import and Export Wizard map nvarchar(max) to its equivalent data type in csv

Tags: ssis, sql-import-wizard

Using SQL Import and Export Wizard i am importing data from csv file to SQL tables,
but in SQL Table is having Column data type nvarchar(max) and i have to convert my data type equivalent to nvarchar(max), i am Tried DT_STR , DT_WSTR,. and according to my R&D i got link that i want to share with you

=> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036.aspx  =>Mapping of Integration Services Data Types to Database Data Types

so there is no such kind of conversion for nvarchar(max). so if anyone knows then do the needful. thanks in advance.

Comment: Used the link to article to get more specific info, I needed to know what to use from my text file to target nvarchar and datetime.  The article shows DT_DBTIMESTAMP -> datetime; and DT_WSTR -> nvarchar. Great question.

Answer (score 7):

You can use text stream [DT_TEXT]  or Unicode text stream [DT_NTEXT].

Resource:

[The SQL Server Integration Services Data Type Map](http://milambda.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/sql-server-integration-services-data.html)

[SSIS to SQL Server Data Type Translations](http://sqlgoutham.blogspot.com/2012/03/ssis-to-sql-server-data-type.html)